# Scss переменные в IE11

Tags: css, scss, node-sass

Есть сторонняя библиотека, использующая scss с переменными
IE переменные не понимает
Как собрать scss, чтобы в итоге в css были уже значения, а не переменные?

Comment: попробуйте юзать css переменные + через что собираете css файл?

Comment: css-переменные - самые настоящие переменные, в то время как scss-переменные перестают быть переменными при компиляции, поэтому просто используйте scss-переменные